# How to start browser activity from a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

i wanna open the browser from my fragment
but when i start my app it crashes
what is wrong ?

```
public class C_spider extends Fragment {

Button btn_off2;

public C_spider() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cspider, container, false);

    btn_off2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_off2);
    btn_off2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            getActivity().startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: We cannot help without a stack trace.

Comment: post the logcat please

Comment: Also show us the exact line throwing the exception so we can get a better idea of what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try putting your codes in the onActivityCreated()

```
public class C_spider extends Fragment {

    Button btn_off2;

    public C_spider() {
     // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cspider, container,   false);  
        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        btn_off2 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_off2);
        btn_off2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            getActivity().startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

 }
```

Comment: Fragment also has a `startActivity()` method, so you don't need to call `getActivity()`.